# Trigger sequence oracle problem

Tags: oracle10g

I have a sequence :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq START WITH 10000001 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

and a table :

```
create table Entry(
id number(5),
name varchar(50)  );
```

I need to increment the value of sequence **after** inserting a row in the Entry table. So i did this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
after INSERT
ON Entry
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT test_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.id FROM dual;
END;
/
```

but '**after**' does not work here but '**before**' works. How can i do it for after?

Comment: Why? What difference would it make when the sequence is incremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want to increment the sequence **after** the insert (which seems peculiar) you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
after INSERT
ON Entry
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT test_seq.nextval INTO l_id FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Of course, this doesn't set the ID of the new row to that sequence value - but if you had wanted to do that, you would have made it a BEFORE trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you call the sequence.nextval in the INSERT statement itself:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
   (id, ...)
VALUES
   (test_seq.nextval, ...)
```

Are you set on using the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php), you can not update the :NEW values while using an AFTER INSERT trigger. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you'd want to increment the sequence after the insert; you're going to lose a significant number of values doing it that way, because the sequence's context CURRVAL can't be interrogated in a session until that session has called NEXTVAL once.

Running the following will raise an ORA-08002:

```
create sequence s1;
select s1.currval from dual;
```

So the way you've coded it with an after insert trigger, where does the first value for entry.id come from?